# Android Media Player sound doesn't work with long-term alarm

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-wake-lock

i made an alarm app with using alarm manager. if i set alarm less than one or two hours its working. but if i set it for more hours alarm manager is working my layout is coming but sound doesn't play. im using wake lock but still its not playing. and after that problem i used sharedPreferences for save my music file's path but not working again. here's my codes i hope i could explain my problem, sorry for my bad english

file chooser

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE:
            // If the file selection was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    // Get the URI of the selected file
                    final Uri uri = data.getData();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Uri = " + uri.toString());
                    try {
                        // Get the file path from the URI
                        path = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Dosya seçildi: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("DosyaSeçici", "Dosya seçerken bir hata oluştu", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    if(data == null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Dosya seçilmedi alarm sesi varsayılan olacak", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(path));
    mp.setLooping(true);
    editor.putString("yol", path);
    editor.commit();
    }
}
```

in my generateNotification function(when alarm time comes up calling this function)

```
try{
          MainActivity.v.vibrate(1);
          mp = new MediaPlayer();
          if(MainActivity.path != null)
              mp.setDataSource(MainActivity.path);
          else
              mp.setDataSource(context, defaultRingtoneUri);
          mp.prepare();
          mp.start();
          mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) 
                {
                    mp.start();
                }});
    }
```

i put 'path = preferences.getString("yol", null)' in onCreate, MainActivity

and my wake lock codes

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
    WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                                     | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                                     | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();
```

permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

i tried to explain my problem with every detail. its working perfect in short-term.
thank you already!

Answer (score 0):

well I didn't programmed an alarm app before, but in my opinion you should look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) at the Google Documentation. Maybe there are some other ways to set up an alarm - i guess it could be solved using a system service - if somebody knows better and I'm wrong please let me know..

Comment: Thank you for answer, but im using alarmManager already and its working but i also using media player for sounds and this is the problem. Probably media player isnt using a service. There isnt something about sound in alarmManager except notification. I hope there is.